Geometric interpretation of the transpose of a matrix
I am trying to understand the argument given by Shilov in the book on Linear Algebra for why the determinant of a transpose of a matrix is the same as the original matrix.
The author says that the determinant of the matrix and its transpose obviously have identical terms. This makes sense since a determinant just adds terms that consist of the product of numbers from each row and column of the matrix. Since we are just switching the rows and columns, the summands must be the same. So all that is to be shown is that each term has identical sign.
A terminology the author uses is "negative slope" which is when a segment whose right endpoint is higher than its left endpoint. The number of segments with negative slope in a summand of the determinant is the number of switches needed to bring it to ascending order 123...n. The number of switches for a summand affects its sign. In particular, if this number is even, there is a positive sign. Else, negative. Hence all that needs to be shown is that the number of negative slope segments for a particular summand does not change after transposition.
Here is the argument given by Shilov for this:
(1) "Transposition of a matrix of a determinant is clearly the result of rotating it through 180 degrees about the principal diagonal"
Can someone provide a diagram that visually shows this? I do not understand how I am supposed to rotate about the diagonal to generate the transpose
(2) "Every segment with negative slope (eg. making an angle $\alpha$ < 90 degree with the rows of the matrix) again becomes a segment with negative slope (i.e. making the angle 90 - $\alpha$ with the rows of the matrix)."
Again I can not understand this visually because I can not understand (1).

PICTORIAL VIEW :

Here we have $6 \times 6$ Matrix where the Principal Diagonal is Purple.
The 3 Blues lines have the "Negative Slope" because the Right End-Point is higher than the Left End-Point.
Shilov wants to rotate the Matrix around the Purple line.
It is 3D rotation , that is , the Matrix starts in the $XY-Plane$ , then goes $90^\circ$ into the $Z-Axis$ , then it goes $90^\circ$ back into the $XY-Plane$ : the Top Right Corner is now the Bottom Left Corner.
It will "look" like this , $90^\circ$ into the $Z-Axis$

It will "look" like this , back into the $XY-Plane$

[[ I used https://pixlr.com/express/ online tool to make that ]]
Here the Blue line with "Negative Slope" continue to have "Negative Slope" , hence the Determinant will not vary.
